# How to create time series for every end date of the year with its corresponding value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have a dataframe that looks like in the following way where the 'Date' column has already datetime64 dtype:

```
           Date     Income_Company_A
0       1990-02-01       2185600.0  
1       1990-02-02       3103200.0
........................................
5467    2011-10-10       29555500.0
5468    2011-10-11       54708100.0
```

How can I get the values for Income_Company_A where the date has to be an ending date for each year, i.e., it has to be 31 Dec for every year starting from 1990 till 2011?
Also, if the value is Null/NaN for the ending date for each year, then how can I fill it up with the value that can be found prior to that date from the dataframe?

The first output with NaN values should look like this:

```
1990-12-31     1593200.0
1991-12-31     4802000.0
1992-12-31     3302000.0
1993-12-31     5765200.0
1994-12-31           NaN
```

Then by replacing the NaN value for the date 1994-12-31 by the value that can be found for a prior date, for example, `1994-12-29 7865200.0`, the final output should look like this:

```
1990-12-31     1593200.0
1991-12-31     4802000.0
1992-12-31     3302000.0
1993-12-31     5765200.0
1994-12-31     7865200.0
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible sample data (prepare a sample df) and show us your desired output as well

Comment: @eshirvana I edited my question. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Why do you take the value of 1993-12-31 to fill 1994-12-31 instead of to take the last valid value of 1994?

Comment: @Corralien I changed the value for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `resample` and take the last valid value of year:

```
out = df.assign(Date=df['Date'].astype('datetime64')).resample('Y', on='Date').last()
```

You can omit `.assign(...)` if your `Date` column has already `datetime64` dtype.

Comment: Yep, it does. Sorry for misinforming by saying the other solution works :) Thank you very much. By the way, how can I use the resample() for a specific column only (e.g. 'Income_Company_A') instead of using it for all the columns throughout my dataframe?

Comment: Like that: `df.assign(Date=df['Date'].astype('datetime64')).resample('Y', on='Date')['Income_Company_A'].last()`?

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realise it could be that simple. Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Date column is already in datetime data type:

```
df.loc[(df['Date'].dt.month == 12) & (df['Date'].dt.day == 31)].ffill()
```

in that case , try this :

```
df.loc[df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)['Date'].idxmax()].ffill()
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, how can I do this for a specific column? Should I use groupby() method?

Comment: you are welcome , not sure what exactly you mean by for a specific column . probably better to ask a new question in SO

Comment: If 1994-12-31 does not exist, there is no 1994 in the output...

Comment: @Corralien true , but it was shown in the sample input data with NaN value , so assumedly it exists with null value

Comment: Yes but you have to take the last valid entry for the current year if the last day is not available.

Comment: @eshirvana I agree with Corralien. The last valid entry has to be taken into account if the record cannot be found for an ending date of a specific year, which is 1994 in this case.

Comment: @neitche ok then , you didn't mention it in your question , maybe add that part to your question as well

Comment: @neitche see updated answer